# Should it be law, or laws? Or do both work?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

In this sentence, should it be law, or laws? Or do both work? Also, if 'laws' is used, should it be 'is' or 'are'?

> ...because laws and enforcement is only used to establish fairness
>
> ...because law and enforcement is only used to establish fairness

Answer (score 3):

'Law' would be a mass noun in that context. It would suggest **every law** is only used for that purpose. That seems unrealistically idealistic. 'Laws' would suggest some laws, but not necessarily all of them, have that purpose. The sentence definitely needs 'are', not 'is', because the 'and' in 'law(s) and enforcement' creates a plural subject of the verb.

Comment: You confirmed what I was thinking, and educated me with the grammar - thank you very kindly !!!